# I can not pipe terminal output to file

Tags: command-line

While gnome terminal shows output of below command, it doesn't pipe it out to text file

```
 xinput test 5
```

shows output in terminal but

```
 xinput test 5 >> text.txt
```

doesn't pipe out to file

EDIT:

"xinput test 5" shows key codes of virtual keyboard. 
I can see output in terminal with " xinput test 5" but not with "xinput test 5 >>text.txt

It shows keycodes from onboard.

EDIT2:

I want to record keystrokes of "onboard" to file
"xinput test 5" shows the keystroke IDs well in terminal but  it doesn't save it to file with " xinput test 5 >> text.txt " it also prevents showing keystroke IDs in terminal. 
"xinput test 5 2>>text.txt" shows output in terminal but doesn't pipe it out to text file.

EDIT3:

You can find virtual keyboard ID with "xinput list"
Interestingly  can see output in terminal with " xinput test 5" but not with "xinput test 5 >>text.txt

Comment: What should be the output of `xinput test 5`? I don't get any output.

Comment: @kenn `xinput test 5` does not give any output on my system. Please clarify on what you expect to happen. Without any output your shell will not redirect any, so you may *think* it's not working.

Comment: "xinput test 5" shows key codes of virtual keyboard.

Comment: @kenn No it doesn't. As far as I can see, for me, it just blocks and local-echoes stuff you type.

Comment: How? I didn't get what you mean. It shows like `key press   36 

key release 36 
key press   57 
key release 57`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is buffered, so nothing goes to the file until the writer (xinput) flushes it.
To force unbuffered output you can use

```
stdbuf -o0 xinput test 5 >out
```

Comment: Wow, here is the master! Thank you enzotib. I'm grateful for the info you shared. It works.

Answer (score 3):

Oddly, redirecting does work normally (I've just tested this with my mouse)... It seems to be a problem specific to the virtual device.

Well this was a much bigger, stranger problem than I initially thought. The short answer is: [it's buffered and when you Control+C, that buffer is lost](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59669/can-a-command-line-program-prevent-its-output-being-redirected). Now, I have no idea *why* it's being buffered for the virtual device and not physical ones.... That's above my pay grade.

How to work around it is pretty simple though (again from [Stephane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/stephane-chazelas) at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59669/can-a-command-line-program-prevent-its-output-being-redirected)):

```
stdbuf -oL xinput test 5 > test
```

---

And the reason you were seeing *some* output before is because they virtual keyboard writes to the active window (like a physical keyboard would).

Comment: @kenn Sorry for jumping the gun there. The command seems to have a fairly large quirk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
xinput test 5 > text.txt
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. I already tried that.

Comment: what was the output of xinput test 5?

Comment: "xinput test 5" shows key codes of virtual keyboard.

Comment: edit the question and then post the output of `xinput test 5`.